# Using Articles in lists

Tags: word-usage

Can you please explain in detail why I "skip" the article before Central Park, "skip" the article before St. Peter's Cathedral and "keep" the article "the" before the Chrysler Building, in the following sentence?

I am an ESL teacher/English Teacher who teaches adults.and it seems this maybe has to do with the context of listing places? I don't know why I am putting the 'the' in at the end and not in the rest of the sentence? I don't know how to explain this one.

We can see(no article) Central Park, (no article) St. Peter's Cathedral, and the Chrysler Building from our room.

Warmly,
Jules

Comment: This has nothing to do with the items being in a list. Central Park and St. Peter's Cathedral just don't have articles.

Comment: I'm a CA and FL licensed English teacher, I understand the general rules, and was wondering if there is an alternative one that explains this usage here so I could explain it to my ESL students, "the" before the Chrysler Building but not for St. Perter's Cathedral, or after Central Park. A shame this was closed. I read the links and none of them answered the question.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for trying; I think it follows the rule where there is a "name" St. Peter, but the Cathedral throws that off a bit. Although parks are man made you could call it a "geographic area," and the Chrysler Building is the only one that strictly follow the "name of a well-known building" category and rule.